# Are subtitles supported in any of the native video controls?

Tags: android, video, localization, subtitle

I'm writing an application with some embedded video content, it's Android 2.2 that I'm targetting. I need to show localized subtitles for the video content.

The video content can be mp4 or 3gp video, played from the SD card.

There are some third party video players out there that already support subtitles, but I haven't seen any open source ones I can bundle, or examine the code for.

So, are there any subtitle enabled controls or are there any open source video player projects which include subtitles?

What options are there for this scenario?

Comment: The project I needed this for was completed some time ago without a solution for this (we went via the streaming of embedded subtitle videos). Hopefully the answers offered here will be of use to someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve the problem.

Something I came across on xda-devs
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=890761

Mplayer was recently ported to Android.

The source for MPlayer is here 
http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html

Best of luck!

Comment: Although I can't test it (the project was completed months ago), this sounds like the closest to an answer I'd get.

Comment: I've downloaded the source and it's written in C. Isn't there any way to do that in Java?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to show subtitles natively on Android. However, if the subtitles are in .srt format, parsing them would be easy: you could just overlay them over a VideoView control that is playing the video.